# Is there a word for baby eater?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that means 'baby eater'? Something like infantovore?

It's for an appeal to the absurd in a philosophy essay.

Comment: I think it's *kinderchomper*.

Comment: According to Jonathan Swift, ["American"](https://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~jlynch/Texts/modest.html) would fit.

Comment: Most educated readers would find "infantivore" understandable; a "paedophage" not quite as much.

Comment: @hemflit Especially *infantivore* is good; it is properly formed and semantically appropriate. *Paedophage* is nice and properly formed, but it means "child-eater". +1

Comment: @hemflit 'Infantivore' gets my vote too, as being much more likely to be understood compared to, say, 'morophage'. If your audience was German, I suppose 'kindlifresser' would work.

Comment: Kindlifresser? That's not German, I'm afraid. The plural for "Kind" is "Kinder", the diminutive form is "Kindchen", not Kindli (where did you get that from, I wonder?) "Kind" is not specifically used for babies, the German word for which is "Baby".

Comment: @JoostKiefte, no need to fear, unless you're a baby: see [Kindlifresserbrunnen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kindlifresserbrunnen). "Kindli is a Swiss German diminutive for the German word Kind, meaning child." Fresser ('snacker', 'eater') has actually made it into English slang. See [Fress](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fresser), under "Related forms".

Comment: It would be ["cannibal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannibalism), I don't believe cannibals have any scruples where eating human flesh is concerned, they will eat people regardless of age, sex or social class.

Comment: Well, Hal, I hope you have read Swift's _A Modest Proposal_ (link in Hot Licks' comment).

Comment: Kiddienosher, Loleata (female child), Grill and Boil chef.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to remain within the realm of already coined expressions, you might try the present participle on for size, "the baby-eating monster" or "the infant-eating troll".

On the other hand coining new expressions can be fun also. If you are unsure whether your audience might object, put it in quotes, the first time you use it: "Many so called 'infantivores' suffer from indigestion"

Bon appétit!

Answer (score -5):

infanticide https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infanticide_%28zoology%29 seems more appropriate unless you want to go for name calling.

Comment: Infanticide is practiced for many reasons other than eating.

Comment: What a waste!!!

Comment: thats what they asked for - baby eater

Comment: @alpa, 'infanticide' denotes an act, 'baby eater' denotes a thing. All baby eaters perpetrate infanticide, but not all people who perpetrate infanticide are baby eaters.

Comment: @Hal The only baby eaters who perpetrate infanticide are the those who kill what they eat.  I would never kill a baby.

Comment: @deadrat Fine point. +1